# Deserialize and persist relationships with JMS Serializer

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

I'm trying to get the following working:

I've got an entity like:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

/**
 * Contact
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */

class Contact
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ServiceClient", inversedBy="contacts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="service_client", referencedColumnName="service_client")
     *
     * @JMS\Type("AppBundle\Entity\ServiceClient")
     * @JMS\SerializedName("serviceClient")
     */
    private $serviceClient;

}
```

I'm sending the following JSON over an HTTP request (Post, it's a new Contact, no ID):

```
{
 "name": "Lorem Ipsum",
 "serviceClient": {"service_client": "ipsum"}
}
```

What I expect is for the JMS Serializer to parse that relationship, and leting me persist the Contact object like this:

```
<?php
$contact = $this->get('serializer')->deserialize(
    $request->getContent(),
    Contact::class, 'json'
);
$this->em->persist($contact);
$this->em->flush();
```

In fact I got that working (I swear it was working) but now it's giving me the follwing error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'AppBundle\Entity\Contact#serviceClient' that was not configured to
>   cascade persist operations for entity:
>   AppBundle\Entity\ServiceClient@000000006fafb93e00007f122bd10320. To
>   solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on
>   this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in
>   the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={\"persist\"}). If you
>   cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement
>   'AppBundle\Entity\ServiceClient#__toString()' to get a clue."

So it's tryign to persist the entity... a thing I do not want since the entity **already** exists. I just want Doctrine to put the reference, the foreign key.

**Edit**: It seems it's the constructor, if I set it to the `doctrine_object_constructor` it works like magic, the thing I do not understand is why it stop working in the first place.

Can anyone share any ideas or a cleaner way to do what I did?

```
    jms_serializer.object_constructor:
    alias: jms_serializer.doctrine_object_constructor
    public: false
```

Comment: When an entity gets serialized, itself and it's related entities get detached from the EntityManager, so when you deserialize it and try to persist, all those related entities will be treated a new entities. You need to "merge" them back to the EntityManager (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/entities-in-session.html).

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens when **Doctrine** cannot map your relationship to an existing record in the database, so it will try to create a new one with the data from the JSON object.

In your case, the JSON object: **{"service_client": "ipsum"}** cannot be mapped to an existing **ServiceClient** instance.

It's because the **default JMS object constructor** call the **unserialize** function (will be the one from your Entity if you defined this method) to construct the object, which mean this object will always be treated by **Doctrine** as new (has never been persisted).

By using **doctrine_object_constructor**, **JMS** will get the object from **Doctrine**. The object came from **Doctrine** not only have the attributes and methods you define in your entity, but also meta-data about whether it's an existing one, it's corresponding row from the database ( so **Doctrine** can detect update made on the record later and handle it), therefore **Doctrine** are able to avoid incorrect persisting.

Comment: Yes, I saw that so far... but I was wondering if there's a method to change the object constructor without placing that configuration line for all the project.

Answer (score -1):

Doctrine will try to persist the Contact with a reference of a ServiceClient entity given in the deserialization. In the entity definition at the level of the manyToOne definition you need to add :

@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ServiceClient", inversedBy="contacts", cascade={"persist"})

Comment: No, the problem is not that the persist fails, the problem is that it has *NOT* to try and persist... The ServiceClient already exists so it's the JMS serializer that has to unserialize it as a Reference to the actual object. It's been solved as I stated on the **edit** at the end, but it's a bit ugly to have it done like that.